Bacterial Growth dataset
Hello guys i'm studying the impact of the use of antibiotics on bacterial growth. For that i need a dataset about bacterial growth (if possible in presence of antibiotics). But it seems like it's impossible to find one that is publicly available. Do you have any recommendations on how i could go about it and if there is any chance that there is a platform that could host one that is public or is there any dataset that you recommend ?
Thank you very much in advance.
